# How to change only specific color of radio button in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have crated angular application for examination in which user gives exam and finally show full report with selected answer I have used ng-repeat for radio button to show options and I want to show user has selected answer and corrected answer if user has selected wrong than its should be red else green but it I have checked using conditions but it changing all radio button colors here is code

```
<div class="md-radio"
             data-ng-repeat="data in vm.examQuestions.allOptions track by $index"
             ng-class="{correct:vm.examQuestions.attemptQuestions.yourChoice === vm.examQuestions.correctanswer ||
             vm.examQuestions.correctanswer === vm.optionsArr[$index],
        'has-error':vm.examQuestions.attemptQuestions.yourChoice !== vm.examQuestions.correctanswer}">
            <span class="lblOption">{{vm.optionsArr[$index]}}</span>
            <input type="radio" id="{{$index+6}}" name="radio{{$index}}" class="md-radiobtn"
                   ng-model="vm.examQuestions.attemptQuestions.yourChoice"
                   ng-value="vm.optionsArr[$index]"
                   ng-disabled="true">
            <label for="{{$index+6}}">
                <span class="inc"></span>
                <span class="check"></span>
                <span class="box"></span>
                <label ng-if="'string' === vm.checkOptionString(data);">{{data}}</label>
                <img ng-src="{{data | examOptions}}" ng-if="'URL' === vm.checkOptionString(data);" width="40px">
            </label>
```

can someone tell me how to apply color only to specific radio button if user has selected right or wrong options
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is easily solvable in a number of ways.

I'd start by checking out ngstyle and ngclass.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Even basic selectors, like querySelectorAll, would do the job of obtaining the desired elements and altering the style of those elements. JQuery can do it too.

I'd explore them all, because you should understand how all work (you may not always work with Angular, and all of the above are commonly encountered). But if you're using Angular, ngstyle and ngclass are definitely things you should have in your holster.

Note that I see you say "Angular" but the tag is "AngularJS". Doesn't really matter, whichever framework you're actually using, ngclass and ngstyle exist and should be something you know.

Comment: I already have used ng-class , I want specific radio button to change color

Comment: The handler for the change event knows which radio button element was selected. Based on the value (you have some way of knowing if it was the right or wrong answer) change the styles or classes of the elements you need to alter. You can do it in a variety of ways, using any of the methods mentioned above. Get your collection of radio buttons, clear all the styles (so the user's previous choices are no longer colored), based on the value of the incoming element, color it red or green.

Answer (score 0):

**First Way** : You can modify your radoi button by modifying css with respect to checked or not!....

```
input[type="radio"] {
  /* remove standard background appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /* create custom radiobutton appearance */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 6px;
  /* background-color only for content */
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 2px solid #bbbbbb;
  background-color: #e7e6e7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* appearance for checked radiobutton */
input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background-color: #93e026;
}

/* optional styles, I'm using this for centering radiobuttons */
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

and you use checked information

```
<input ..... [checked]="item.selected" ..... />
```

**Second Way** can be using ng-class like as;

```
<div ... data-ng-repeat="..." ....>
 <input type="radio" ng-class="{classSelected: item.selected, classNotSelected: !item.selected}"/>
</div>
```

**Third Way** can be using ng-class like as;

```
<div ... data-ng-repeat="..." ....>
 <input type="radio" ng-style="selectedStyle" ng-change="selectedStyle={color:'red'}"/>
</div>
```